# How do you say ‘You will heal’ in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How do you say ‘You will heal’ in Latin?
I mean this in a way of being able to mentally heal.

Answer (score 8):

"Heal" in English is what's called an "ergative verb". When it's used with a single noun, that noun is the person who gets better; when it's used with two nouns, the subject is the doctor, the object is the person who gets better.

The relevant verbs in Latin unfortunately don't have that property: if it's used with a single noun, that noun is the doctor. So a literal translation of "you will heal" would be more like "you will make people better".

So instead, I would use a passive verb: literally, "you will be healed". Passive verbs in Latin also sometimes have a "middle" meaning, something like "you will heal yourself".

Conveniently, this is a single word in Latin: **sānāberis** for a single person, **sānābiminī** for multiple people.

If you want to express what exactly will be good for their health, you can add a noun in the ablative. If you want to say they will be healed by *time*, for example (because time heals all wounds), add the word **tempore**; if you want to say they will be healed by *therapy*, add the word **therapīā**, and so on.

Comment: Thank you everyone - this has been very helpful!

Answer (score 7):

Celsus (c. 25 BC – c. 50 AD) often uses the intransitive verb *sanescere* in his *De Medicina* to express the **non-causative** change of state meaning.

> *Insanientes sub somno sanescunt* (Cels. 3, 18).

Unlike *sanari*, which is in principle ambiguous between a passive interpretation (involving an (implicit) agent/cause: "by someone/something") and a middle one (cf. Draconis's answer), notice that *sanescere* is not ambiguous. So ***sanesces*/*sanescetis*** is a better translation for 'You will heal' if an **internal** process is involved.

As for the use of adjuncts pointed out by Draconis, here are my choices/preferences: *tempore* is compatible with both *sanari* and *sanescere*, whereas *therapia* is probably better with *sanari* (NB: only the latter involves an **external** cause).

Comment: Excellent answer! Just going to leave this in a comment for OP: _sanārī_ is the infinitive ("basic" form) of the verb I used in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with the abbreviations used in English online communications and I've just discovered that OP means 'original poster'. I was wondering if you could provide me with a link where I can find the most frequent ones. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately I've learned them through trial and error so I don't know of a good reference. OP is the only one I can think of that's common on StackExchange though. (Also maybe SE meaning StackExchange, so we're on Latin.SE now.)